# How to disable signature validation when using JwtSecurityTokenHandler?

Tags: validation, jwt, access-token, identityserver3

We would like to use JwtSecurityTokenHandler from System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt namespace for JWT tokens validation in our application API layer. 
Btw, we use IdentityServer3 as authorization server that our clients use to obtain an access token and then call different applications' APIs.

For starters, we just need *basic* validation like validate issuer and that token is not expired. But we have next error:

> SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier (

We have searched through TokenValidationParameters options, tried different option to disable almost all boolean flags, but it is still present.

Is it possible to suppress signature validation, so that we do not have to manage public keys of authorization server's certificate?